# Objective C - Call another class

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, header-files, theos

I use a class that returns array as the following :

```
%hook firstHeader
-(void)firstMethod:(id)array{
    NSLog(@"Array %@", array);

   return %orig;
}
%end
```

the nslog result :

```
array (
  "<secondHeader: 0x17a2f3c0>",
  "<secondHeader: 0x17a2f530>",
  "<secondHeader: 0x17a2f5b0>",
  "<secondHeader: 0x17a2f720>"
)
```

Bear with me but I may sound dumb here; 
how can i use the result's array object with `secondHeader`,
As `secondHeader` ( or secondClass ) contains methods

**Summary** : First class's method returns array with objects, it wants me to use those objects with another class/header which is `secondHeader`

Comment: Please edit your code so that we can have a look. Also please elaborate ur question more clearly

Comment: What does %hook firstHeader mean? What is %orig?

Comment: Is it so that you want to pass the Array contents from one class to another?

Comment: %hook is a theos method to hook into classes, specifically theos/ios

Comment: I want to pass array objects from one class to another, NSLog results return `<secondHeader: 0x17a2f5b0>"`, Does the `0x17a2f5b0` stand for memory data ?, How can i use it with `secondHeader`'s methods

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment "First class's method returns array with objects, it wants me to use those objects with another class/header which is secondHeader". Simply declare a property in `secondHeader` class as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * yourArray;
```

Synthesize it in .m File as:

```
@synthesize yourArray
```

And in your `First class` simple initialize the instance of `secondHeader` as set the value for *yourArray* as:

```
-(void)firstMethod:(id)array
{
    NSLog(@"Array %@", array);

    secondHeader * secondClass = [[secondHeader alloc] init];
    secondClass.yourArray = array;

    return %orig;
}
```

Once array contents are passed to secondClass, you can access the array contents by Index as:

```
id obj = [yourArray objectAtIndex:1];   //id is Generic data type. You should set the right data type.
```

Hope this will help. Ofcourse there can be other ways to pass the data, but this is the simplest way.